How can you display product variation fields?
For Commerce  products with variations, when you go to "Manage Display", there is a virtual field called "Variations" with the option of rendering it as an "Add to Cart Form".
Without DS installed, or with the layout set to "None", when I enable this "Variations" field it shows all the fields that are enabled in the display for the product variation type, as well as a dropdown to select the variation (by attribute). When you select a variation from the dropdown, AJAX is applied and the field values change. So far so good.
But when I choose a Display Suite layout for the product type, this breaks. All the product variation fields disappear and only the dropdown is shown.
This is how it looks without DS installed or with the layout set to "None":

When I enable DS and choose any layout, for example the "Two Column" layout, it changes to this:

Apparently this used to be an issue - see Commerce Product using Display Suite - but according to one of their devs, it has now been resolved - see https://www.drupal.org/project/ds/issues/2725077#comment-15373081
Is this is regression bug, or is there something I need to do to make Display Suite render those fields?
I'm on Drupal 10.3, DS 3.24 and Commerce 2.40
